# Mirror Networking; How to Pass/Sync c# actions?

Tags: unity, unity-networking, unet, mirror-networking

Since you can not pass actions as parameters to commands and rpc calls, how would you sync actions ? My main goal is to find an easy and generic way for objects to easily do actions from their local player. Something like:

```
_localPlayer.RunFromLocalToAllPlayers(()=>
{
    //MyAction
});
```

Local Player having these methods:

```
private Action _callbackForAllPlayers;
public void RunFromLocalPlayerToAllPlayers(Action callback)
{
    _callbackForAllPlayers = callback;
    Debug.Log(_callbackForAllPlayers);
    CmdRunFromLocalPlayerToAllPlayers();
}

[Command]
        private void CmdRunFromLocalPlayerToAllPlayers()
        {
            Debug.Log($"Running on server");
            RpcRunFromLocalPlayer();
        }

[ClientRpc]
        private void RpcRunFromLocalPlayer()
        {
            Debug.Log($"Running on client");
            _callbackForAllPlayers?.Invoke();
            Debug.Log(_callbackForAllPlayers);
        }
```

and of course that local Action variable is being null on other clients since i can not sync it or pass it as parameter.

Comment: Why don't you just broadcast a RPC to all players?

Comment: Of course i can go straight and use different Commands and different RPC calls for every action but i am looking for an easy and generic solution to this thats why.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to do that than broadcasting a RPC. That seems to be exactly the purpose of RPC's and where they should be used. Could you please expand more on why you want to avoid using RPCs in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: I mean the question has my purpose and i already wrote my purpose with my first comment but here it is again, i am trying to find a generic solution for those kinda Command and RPC calls because otherwise whenever i would like to do something i have to write different command/rpc calls each time for every different action in the game.

Comment: I understood you are trying to avoid using RPC's all over the code. What I asked you is to expand more on that. What is so bad about writing different RPC's for any different action you want to broadcast in your game? As I said before this is **exactly** the purpose of the remote procedure call mechanism.

Comment: There is no more than what i have said, sorry.

Comment: @andresantacruz I'm attempting to do this in 2021. My reason is to decouple the behavior of individual GameObjects from the actual networking layer. I have a fairly deterministic game, so if I can get every RPC to correspond with an Action, I can invoke those actions directly to write Unity PlayTests against prefabs in a networkless environment.

Comment: Best I've come up with so far is to get the string name of  the event to send over the wire. Doesn't feel great to me.